# React tableau visualization component doesn't rerender when path prop changes

Tags: reactjs, iframe, rendering, tableau-api

I have a webpage that displays a react component, TableauReports, which shows a tableau dashboard.
This is the `TableaReports` component:

```
const TableauReports = ({ selectedBtn }) => {

    console.log(`selectedBtn = ${selectedBtn}`)

    return (
      <div className='tableauPlaceholder' style={{ width: '1400px', height: '950px' }}>
        <object className='tableauViz' width='1400' height='950' style={{ display: 'none' }}>
          <param name='host_url' value='https%3A%2F%2Ftableauanalytical-east.cloud.privateSite.com%2F' />
          <param name='embed_code_version' value='3' />
          <param name='site_root' value='&#47;t&#47;A_B_C' />
          <param name='name' value={`Reports/${selectedBtn.replace(" ", "")}`} />
          <param name='tabs' value='yes' />
          <param name='toolbar' value='yes' />
          <param name='showAppBanner' value='false' />
        </object>
      </div>
    )
  }

export default TableauReports
```

And within my `app.jsx` the component is accessed like so:

```
const [selectedTableauBtn, setSelectedTableauBtn] = useState(constants.TableauButtons[2]);

// some code that sets the selectedTableauBtn... 

<TableauReports selectedBtn={selectedTableauBtn}></TableauReports>
```

The component indeed is accessed every time `selectedTableauBtn` changes as the console.log in `TableauReports` is triggered and it prints the correct value. The problem is: the tableau dashboard doesn't switch tabs as it should. In fact, the dashboard doesn't rerender at all! Why isn't the dashboard rerendering and displaying the updated visualization as specified by the input `selectedBtn`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking some Tableau docs here regarding [embedded code](https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/embed_code.htm) they seem to use `&#47;` as a delimiter.

Example:

> ```
> <object class='tableauViz' width='800' height='600' style='display:none;'>
>    <param name='host_url' value='https%3A%2F%2Fonline.tableau.com%2F' /> 
>    <param name='site_root' value='&#47;t&#47;Sales' /> 
>    <param name='name' value='MyCoSales&#47;SalesScoreCard&#47;' /> 
>    <param name='tabs' value='yes' /> 
>    <param name='toolbar' value='yes' />
> </object>
> ```

Given that I can't find much of any documentation regarding Tableau's embedding coding syntax I suggest matching the syntax.

```
<param name='name' value={`Reports&#47;${selectedBtn.replace(" ", "")}&#47;`} />
```

If this fails to get the iframe to refresh then you may just need a bigger hammer to force remount the element using a React key.

```
const TableauReports = ({ selectedBtn }) => {
  console.log({ selectedBtn });

  return (
    <div
      className='tableauPlaceholder'
      style={{ width: '1400px', height: '950px' }}
    >
      <object
        key={selectedBtn} // <-- key to remount `object`
        className='tableauViz'
        width='1400'
        height='950'
        style={{ display: 'none' }}
      >
        <param
          name='host_url'
          value='https%3A%2F%2Ftableauanalytical-east.cloud.privateSite.com%2F'
        />
        <param name='embed_code_version' value='3' />
        <param name='site_root' value='&#47;t&#47;A_B_C' />
        <param
          name='name'
          value={`Reports&#47;${selectedBtn.replace(" ", "")}&#47;`}
        />
        <param name='tabs' value='yes' />
        <param name='toolbar' value='yes' />
        <param name='showAppBanner' value='false' />
      </object>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an external lib that uses vanilla js, it's probably not detecting the dom changes react is performing, thus not updating the viz. In cases like this, personally I just put a custom key on the component. It'll cause a full rerender, so that might not be viable for you, but it should work.

Something like

```
<TableauReports selectedBtn={selectedTableauBtn} key={selectedTableauBtn} />
```

or

```
<object key={selectedBtn}>...</object>
```